# Checkbox inside map not getting checked

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to react and trying to create a todo app using react hooks. I have an array todoList which i'm displaying inside unordered list and there is a checkbox for every todo element.Now, issue is the checkbox state is not getting changed on click. What am i missing? in OnChange i tried by directly changing item.isDone property and also i tried using setTodoList as well but in both cases there is nothing happening in UI. useForm is just another module that uses useState.

```
const App = () => {
  const [todoVal, handleChange] = useForm({
    todoValue: "",
  });
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Todo Item {todoVal.todoValue}</h1>
        <div className="row">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Write a todo"
            className="form-control"
            required
            name="todoValue"
            value={todoVal.todoValue}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <button
            className="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
            onClick={() => {
              setTodoList([
                ...todoList,
                {
                  id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
                  isDone: false,
                  value: todoVal.todoValue,
                },
              ]);
            }}
            disabled={!todoVal.todoValue.length}
          >
            Add Todo
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <ul className="list-group">
            {todoList.map((item, idx) => {
              return (
                <li key={item.id} className="list-group-item">
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-8 px-2">
                      <input
                        id={"isDone-" + item.id}
                        type="checkbox"
                        name={"isDone-" + item.id}
                        checked={item.isDone}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                             item.isDone = !item.isDone;
                        }}
                      />
                      <label for={"isDone-" + item.id}>{item.value} - {String(item.isDone)}</label>
                    </div>
                    <button
                      className="btn btn-danger"
                      onClick={() => {
                        const list = todoList.filter(
                          (todoItem) => todoItem.id !== item.id
                        );
                        setTodoList(list);
                      }}
                    >
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: You have to update the todoList onChange of radio button. You can track the record using the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the onChange in input checkbox to

```
onChange ={ (e) => {
  // item.isDone = !item.isDone; you cannot change item directly as it's immutable
  setTodoList(
    todoList.map((it) =>
      it.id !== item.id ? it : { ...item, isDone: !item.isDone }
    )
  );
}}
```

***Explaination***: item object is immutable, so it is todoList. So when you want to set its property isDone to true you have to create a proxy copy and then use setTodoList.

So we call setTodoList and generate the copy of todoList with map. If id is different from the one that you are checking we keep todoItem (it in my code) as it is, else we create a copy of it with the spread operator {...} and update its isDone property to true.

We could also use `immer` to generate a proxy mutable object that we can edit directly but I think in this simple case is overkilled.

For the sake:
install immer with `npm i immer`

on the top: `import {produce} from 'immer';`
then:

```
onChange ={ (e) => {
 setTodoList(
    todoList.map((it) =>
      it.id !== item.id ? it : produce(item, (draftItem) => {
        draftItem.isDone = !draftItem.isDone;
      })
    )
  );
}}
```

Comment: But is there any better way to handle this? What is the array size is very large?

Comment: I don't think that this can be done in other way. My PC with chrome loaded 10000 dinamically generated todoitems within 10 seconds, I don't think you will have so much element in a single page of a frontend app. Also when I click the checkbox it takes 2 seconds to complete execution and re-render.

Answer (score 0):

You already have an index, so you don't need to map through the list. You can create a copy of array and update specific index:

```
onChande={ () => {
  setTodoList((prevTodoList) => {
    // create a copy of todoList
    const updatedTodoList = [...prevTodoList];

    // toggle isDone state at specific index
    updatedTodoList[idx].isDone = !updatedTodoList[idx].isDone;

    return updatedTodoList;
  });
}}
```

Same thing can be applied to your delete method, so you won't be needing to filter through whole list:

```
onClick={ () => {
  setTodoList((prevTodoList) => {
    // create a copy of todoList, needed because splice mutates array
    const updatedTodoList = [...prevTodoList];

    // remove item at specific index, mutates array
    updatedTodoList.splice(idx, 1);

    return updatedTodoList;
  });
}}
```

Comment: You're right, I tested this on a 10 million objects list. While with map took 230 ms to run, your code took 50ms. However, we're talking about a 10 million's item list, but yes, your code is more efficient.

Comment: Yes 10 million's item list is highly unlikely and performance in this code shouldn't be a factor. In my opinion a factor in this is simple and easy to read code, utilizing the things that are already available. Simplicity often results in easy to understand and readable code, which in many situations are also more efficient.